# git - create mode 100644 for deleted file

Tags: git

This is my pre-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "removing file.txt"
rm file.txt
exit 0
```

and this is the output for git commit:

```
$ git commit -m "test"
removing file.txt
[master (root-commit) b82b2e1] test
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file.txt
```

Why does it recognize file.txt ?? Is it because it's not included in gitignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what, precisely, you mean by the verb *recognize*, but the main issue here is that Git does not make commits from the *work-tree*.  Git makes commits from the *index*.

When you `git add file.txt`, that copies the contents of `file.txt` from the work-tree into the index.  If the file `file.txt` did not appear in the index before, it does now.  If it *was* in the index before, the old index contents are now replaced with whatever was in the work-tree `file.txt`.

When you run `git commit`, that takes *whatever is in the index right now* and turns that into a commit.  In your pre-commit hook, you modify the work-tree, but not the index—so the index remains as it was, and the file goes into the commit.

Answer (score 1):

If you already added the file to git in the past girt **will track** it until you tell it not to = delete it.

`.gitignore` will not help you in this case since its already tracked.

You have to do this:

```
# remove it from the index and commit it
git rm --cached <file.txt>
```

and now add it to the .gitignore and commit it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have added the file to `.gitignore`, it would not have been added to the index unless you force it to, so I guess you want to put it to `.gitignore` instead. If you still want to do it via `pre-commit` hook, you should remove the file from the index, not the worktree, so use `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -- file.txt` instead of `rm file.txt` in your `pre-commit` hook to remove the file from the index if present, instead of removing it from the worktree.